# swift convenience initializer call other convenience initializer inherit from superclass

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

[image]

```
class AreaSectorLineOverlay: MKPolyline {
var id: String!
var nickName: String!
var locationName: String!

convenience init(coordinates coords: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: Int, id: String, nickName: String, locationName: String) {
    self.init(coordinates: coords, count: count)
    self.id = id
    self.nickName = nickName
    self.locationName = locationName
}
```

}

Why the code is wrong? error is ('self' used before self.init call) and at last of the  function 'init(coordinates coords: UnsafePointer, count: Int, id: String, nickName: String, locationName: String)' the error is (Self.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer)

[image]

```
class A {
    var a1: String!

    init() {
    }

    convenience init(a1: String) {
        self.init()
        self.a1 = a1
    }
 }

 class B: A {
     var b1: String!

     convenience init(a1: String, b1: String) {
         self.init(a1: a1)
         self.b1 = b1
     }
 }

 let b = B(a1: "a1Test", b1: "b1Test")
 print(b.a1, b.b1)
```

There is no error like this,and print result is (a1Test b1Test)

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: The question is the first paragraph of the code is wrong, but the second paragraph of the code is correct